# How to read input with c++ using program.exe < text.txt

Tags: c++, file, iostream, cin

I have to read input according to these rules:

> "The input consists of several lines of text. Some lines may be empty. The input can be fed from a file, using a line such as `prog.exe < input.txt` in which case the end of input is indicated appropriatelly by the operating system. If you enter input using a keyboard, there is normally a way to signal the end of input with some control key, depending on the operating system (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> in Unix/Linux-style systems, and <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> in Microsoft systems)."

Previously I have been doing it this way

```
while(getline(cin, data)) {
     if(data == "0") break;
     / * do stuff */
}
```

So I can read as many lines as I want and preform calculations, and then when I'm done just type a 0 and end my program. I tried entering a list of things in a .txt file one per line, and then calling `program.exe < myfile.txt` but nothing happened.

What's this `< file.txt` doing?

How can I properly handle content inside it when calling my program like that?

And how can I make it calculate things when you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>?

Comment: If, for example, in Windows, you issue the command `dir`, it will list the contents of the current directory. Issuing `dir > thisDir.txt` will redirect the output to the specified text file. This logic can be used to answer part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraphrasing the text of your exercise:

Using `command1 < file1` executes `command1`, with `file1` as the *source of input* (as opposed to the keyboard).

This is known as *redirecting standard input.*

`std::cin` will get its input from `file1` instead of from the keyboard.

The end of the input file is analogous to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (on Microsoft systems, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on most others). Once [**`std::getline()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reaches the end of the file (or you read a line with just "0"), you'll exit your `while`-loop and then you can do your calculation on the `data` you've collected (and presumably stored in some container).

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like homework...

Hint 1: `>`, `<`, `<<`, `>>` are "input/output redirect" for shell (CMD on Windows).

Hint 2: getline returns result (RTFM i.e. http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline if you would use C version or for C++ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/ and corresponding istream methods)

Comment: No, he's clearly calling getline(istream&, string&), not getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*), so it doesn't return the result, it just returns cin.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes, the C-style comments do conflict with the C++ tag.